# Sorting the ListView elements and according to that an other String Array also sorting

Tags: android

> I have one ListView & two String Arrays
>   For example One String Array have all countries that is Adopted with ListView & other string 
>   Array have their capitals,I'm using the TextWathcher & when it is enter the data in EditText
>   when I click on the ListView,according to that Capitals String element also sorting
>   & display the relevant element should display by PopupWindow

```
adapter_countries = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,allCountries_list);//this is Listview & have coutries      `array`
all_countries_list_view.setAdapter(adapter_countries);
all_countries_list_view.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Comment: I don't understand you, can you please be more specific or reformulate your question

Comment: sure,listview is having String Array & relevantly I have String Array & when ListView Values are sorting by TextWatcher according to that relevant String Array value should display

Comment: I think, I've got it, You have and EditText where the users enter some  letters for a quick search or something like that, and the arraylist that has the countries is sorting by relevance, but you need the other arraylist (the one with the capitals) that sort too?

Comment: For example : ListView have All countries,when we using the textwatcher & click on element,according to that capital should display,by more detailed:ListView have Countries:USA,England,India,Pakistan,Astralia,Srilanka. and relevantly for capitals in an other string those are "Washington,D.C ","London","Delhi","Islamabad","Canberra","Colombo"   & now I'm searching the country in EditText,according to that Value will display

Comment: ok,please tell me how,according to above example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating a subclass that include the country and capital, and make an arrayList from those objects, so you will have to sort just for the countries and the capitals will be asociated to the same item.

```
public class MyObject
    {
        String country;
        String capital;

        public MyObject()
        {
            this.country = "";
            this.capital = "";
        }
        public MyObject(String newCountry, String newCapital)
        {
            this.country = newCountry;
            this.capital = newCapital;
        }

        public String getCapital()
        {
          return this.capital;
        }
        public String getCountry()
        {
            return this.country;
        }
    }
```

and then make an arraylist of this new object:

```
ArrayList<MyObject> myArray = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
```

fill the array, and when you sort, just made the same sorting you're using for the countries but with `myArray.get(index).getCountry()`

Comment: Thanks so much,I'l do like that.